# Iterating through a filtered list returns undefined

Tags: javascript, screeps

Can someone explain why `harvesters[i]` would return `undefined` in this case? I've used similar code before with no issues. This is for the game Screeps.

```
  var harvesters=_(Game.creeps).filter( { memory: { role: 'harvester' } } );

  for(var i in harvesters)
  {
    //console.log(harvesters[i]); //this is the debug code I mention below
    harvesters[i].memory.sourceid=0;
  }
}
```

After some testing (thanks to the comments) I found that `harvesters[i]` did not return the harvester object I expected.... each `harvester` is apparently an instance of

```
function wrapperValue() {
      return baseWrapperValue(this.__wrapped__, this.__actions__);
    }
```

when I try outputting it to console. Why isnt this a creep object?

Comment: Isn't `.filter()` supposed to be called with a function?

Comment: @Pointy Yes, a predicate that decides which functions are kept. I would expect this to return an error.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=example

Comment: `Game.creeps` returns a list of all creeps in the game, and the filter is for `role: 'harvester'`. Right?

Comment: Agreeing on the fact that an *array* filter needs a closure or function handle, but this is the filter method of the return value of `_( ... )`, which is probably the underscore framework.  I would think that would mean it's a filter on a collection, which might work.  Without knowing the framework used, though, it's hard to tell.

Comment: Maybe OP needs to run that object through [`matcher()`](http://underscorejs.org/#matcher) first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently using lodash's chained sequence functionality, in order to extract the unwrapped value you'll need to call [`.value()`](https://lodash.com/docs/3.10.1#prototype-value).

Your code will have to look somewhat like this:

```
const harvesters = _(Game.creeps).filter(
  {
    memory: {
      role: 'harvester'
    }
  }
).value();
```

Alternatively you can use [`_.filter`](https://lodash.com/docs/3.10.1#filter) directly:

```
const harvesters = _.filter(Game.creeps, {
  memory: {
    role: 'harvester'
  }
});
```